# HQL - update query is not woring

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, hibernate-batch-updates

I have done the Hibernate implementation.Here is a code related to update function.

```
 Query updateQuery = session.createQuery(" update User set registered = '1' " + " where user_activation_key = '"+userUUID+"'");
 int result = updateQuery.executeUpdate();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'm getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update [ update com.shop.domain.User set registered = '1'  where user_activation_key = '04c42f1c-a55d-49cd-8bde-8d340f054d76']
at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:209)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
at com.shop.service.ORMService.isUserAvailable(ORMService.java:56)
at com.shop.service.ORMService.activateUserAccount(ORMService.java:39)
at com.shop.web.controller.Test.main(Test.java:10)                    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:104)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.PreprocessingParser.token(PreprocessingParser.java:131)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:61)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:239)
... 10 more
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>


    <mapping resource="com/shop/domain/User.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

What is this, **query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update** ? Need some help?

Comment: Please post the hibernate configuration file?

Comment: [Check this site also](http://enlightensoft.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/how-to-resolve-org-hibernate-queryexception-for-delete-hql-query/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In configuration file, change the property `hibernate.query.factory_class` value
From

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
```

To

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

See more [forum.hibernate.org](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944696)

---

### Side Note

Use `Query.setParameter()` method to pass parameter to query

```
Query updateQuery = session.createQuery("update User set registered = '1' 
                       where user_activation_key = :userUUID");
updateQuery.setParameter("userUUID", userUUID);
```

Answer (score 1):

HQL uses class name instead of table name, and property names instead of column name. I think your issue is related to this.

Do you also import the correct Query?

Comment: yes ..i think it's not the issue because in another method SELECT query works fine. Query query = session.createQuery(" from User ");.This works fine

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate provides two kinds of HQL parser implementation

1. org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
2. org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

and we mentione that in our “hibernate.cfg.xml” configuration file like below

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Or

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

**This configuration is optional**, if you do not configure the HQL parser implementation explicitly then your **default HQL parser implementation** will be ***org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory*.** 
To resolve your issue, either **remove the entry of hibernate.query.factory_class from your hibernate.cfg.xml** file, so that hibernate can use default HQL parser implementation or **change it to org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory from 
org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory**.