# Errors in named queries delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am getting an error

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: GroupKPI.deleteKPIList`

in this query :
`@NamedQuery(name="GroupKPI.deleteKPIList" , query="delete from GroupKPI kpi where kpi.kpiKey in :list2BDeleted")`

class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUP_KPI")
public class GroupKPI implements Serializable{
    public GroupKPI() { }
    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupKpiKey kpiKey; 
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

I need to pass a list of `GroupKPI` to the query
I am using hibernate 3.3.0

**EDIT :**

The whole log :

`org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: delete`

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457355/hql-update-query-is-not-woring) that the error is fixed by applying the parser `org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` but the project is old and might have some old queries so the parser cant be changed safely ... so any other suggestions or alternative syntax?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Can you please provide the whole stacktrace there must be more info